# How to set container width to child in flex box with flex-direction as column and flex-wrap as wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is the working code:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: center;
  alighn-item: center;
}

.child{
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.childItem{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
    <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
    <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
    <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
    <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

**We want this child container (yellow) width should equal to the child item (red) elements**

Comment: You just add `flex: 1;` to the `.child`

Comment: @MerajKhan no, it doesn't work how it supposes to be

Comment: Can you provide the image that you want as the output, that would be more explanatory.

Comment: specify a width on the container, put flex on the child flex:0 0 60%;

Comment: @MerajKhan i have updated question, check expected output

Comment: @Piyush Dhamecha First you have to give `width` or `flex-basis` to the `.child`. In your code to give `width: 100px` to the childItem  thats the reason container taking width 100px based on width auto and the next items overflow. Add this to the `.child`  `flex: 0 0 12%; `

Comment: @MerajKhan why should we need to specify `width`, what will heppen if there is multiple child item which excides the width.

Comment: @CarolMcKay can we do without specifying width, width should be auto to child item

Comment: @Piyush Dhamecha  If you want to do like this then give `flex: 0 0 100%`

Comment: @MerajKhan `flex: 0 0 100%` takes full width, it should be the width of the child item element, did you test it in codepen, is that giving expected result?

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha i tried like this https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/YJJRzo

Comment: @MerajKhan what if there is one or two child item, its taking 50% of the width, it should not be, we don't want to be a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test-container{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.container{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width:300px;
  margin:auto;
}

.child{
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.childItem{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
  <div class='container'>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div class='child'>
      <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
      <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
      <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
      <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
      <div class="childItem">Amounts</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If we add more items it is overflowing.

Comment: You can adjust container width. If you keep width auto then it will place elements to cover available width.